# Set calculated date field to null in podio (and thus with javascript)

Tags: javascript, datetime, podio

Here's the issue with Podio. I have a calculation field that is set to return a date and it does that well if I only enter a reference to a date field from the item. What I want is for the calculation field to return a null date (as part of an IF statement) and thus leave or make the field empty (and therefore not show up in the calendar).

Something like this:

```
var date = DateFieldFromPodioItem;

if (whatever) {
moment(date).add(2, "weeks").toDate();
}
else {
//RETURN NULL HERE
};
```

I have tried setting `var zero = null` and have it return that. Which yields me an `Invalid date` error.

I also tried using `.setFullYear(null,null,null)` along with `.setHours(null,null,null,null)` to set `date` and return that. I set `date` to 1 January 0001 12:00:00.000 AM as was suggested somewhere (I forgot where I read that). The first got me a rather unfriendly: `Invalid value datetime.datetime(1753, 9, 12, 22, 43, 41, 128000) (datetime): Dates before year 1900 are not supported`. The second did too, with slightly different numbers within the ().

I even tried the rather silly idea of entering no code within `else`, but that also returns `Invalid date`.

Any ideas?

----EDIT----

Turns out that even while Podio shows the message `Invalid date` it lets you save the field anyway and when changing field values so if=false it shows no longer a date in the calculation field. Thanks to Rainer Grabowski for pointing that out to me. If someone @Podio reads this, perhaps fix that?
I'll leave this here to perhaps help someone else, as I have found the answer to my questions on here rather often.

Comment: There is no "null date". A javascript (i.e. ECMAScript) Date object is based on a [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1), which is a number of milliseconds before or after the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). The result of `new Date(value)` (where *value* is optional) will either be a valid Date object or `NaN` (presuming that an error isn't thrown).

Comment: Thanks Rob! I shouldn't have been thrown off by the error messages that Podio returned. Especially the 'Invalid date' ones. It lets me save even with the error message an behaves as it should. `null` in the else works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Should work, but I didn't test:

```
var date = DateFieldFromPodioItem;
var returnValue = null;

if (whatever) {
  returnValue = moment(date).add(2, "weeks").toDate();
}

returnValue;
```